# SQL Server hangs when I use ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server

If I use this query, SQL Server hangs or need a long time to execute the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 mssid 
FROM my_table 
WHERE serial = 'myserialcode' 
ORDER BY times DESC;
```

This query is simple, it should show me the latest entry from serial. The Table has 700k records, this should not the problem, right?

If I remove `ORDER BY times DESC` it's working fast, but I don't get the latest record.

Workaround query, does not working too:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE serial = 'myserialcode' 
  AND times = (SELECT MAX(times) 
               FROM my_table 
               WHERE serial = 'myserialcode')
```

Datatypes:

- serial = VARCHAR 20
- times = BIGINT 19,0

Thanks,
Gregor

EDIT:
I talked with the Server Administrator of the SQL Server, he told me, that the table is broken(?). 3 days ago, the query worked without problems. He will fix it, so I think it's solved.
Anyway, I will create an index on mssid and times, and use specified fields instead of * in future, thanks!

EDIT 2: The table or a row from table was broken and killed the query. Now it works again, 0,031 sec :)
The query for indexing hanged also. And if I used the query above, with other serial, it worked.

Comment: Sorting is a costly operation which will take time. If possible add index on `serial` and `times`

Comment: Indexes on what columns?

Comment: If you don't already have it - try adding an index on `serial` and include the  `mssid`: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX01_YourTable ON dbo.YourTable(serial) INCLUDE(mssid);` - does that improve performance at all? Is there an index on `times`, too?

Comment: How long is a long time?

Answer (score 0):

Add a desc index to times

Then use your first SQL statement, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention so this is a shot in the dark but if mssid is an incremental field you should be able to get the row you want just using

```
ORDER BY mssid DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Select top (1) *
From My_table with (unlock)
Where serial = 'mysrialcode'
Order by time desc

I think it could be transaction issue.
I wouldn't suggest you index your
Time field/column
But check indexing on 'myserialcode'
Or at best use data tuning adviser for help.

Also using * is bad for optimizing. Use selected fields/columns.

I hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Aside from the recommendation about `*`, this is dangerous advice. First, `unlock` is not a keyword in MS SQL Server. Second, using `with NOLOCK` (which is what you probably meant means that you will get dirty reads - uncommitted transactions will be read as though they're real - which means that in a transactional system, the results of this query **may not represent the real data**. [NOLOCK is not a turbo button](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/nolock-is-not-a-turbo-button/)

Comment: Thanks @alroc, I meant (nolock). I understand what isolation transaction is, I was assuming he could be facing a locking issues. All the same, thanks for bringing it up.